# Qlik Sense and JWT authentication

Tags: authentication, qliksense, jwt

I am trying to get Qlik Sense to work using JWT auth, instead of our current header based auth. Has anyone been successful with this? Would anyone who's gotten this working be able to help me out? Even a sample working example is fine. I can try to follow through the process there to get it to work in mine.

Server Version: November 2017 release

Note: I am still pretty a newbie to Qlik, so hoping for considerate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the example provided in [enigma.js](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/tree/master/examples/authentication/sense-using-jwt) repo

Comment: Thank you. Shall look into this and post back here the status.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, I don't know if there is any restriction on the super root user trying to auth with JWT, every time I get this error **The user cannot be authenticated by the JWT through the following virtual proxy**, I followed the same steps documented here https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-19383